# Hyphenated tags are not working in search anymore

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-search, site-specific

I have a tag favourited on Stack Overflow called *android-wear*. However, when I click on it, the search box just shows *[android]* and results for Android are displayed which is a far broader category obviously.

Also if you manually search for *[android-wear]* it changes to *[android]*.

This was working fine last week, so it has only just been changed.

Comment: a) this sounds like a question for [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) unless it's happening for all hyphenated tags on all sites or b) it's because the tags have been synonymised - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/synonyms

Comment: The `android-wear` tag is now a synonym of `android`.

Comment: Can I no longer filter a search to just android-wear then?

Comment: See [Undo the \[android-wear\] -> \[android\] tag synonym again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289310)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I have upvoted that question as it's really annoying as Android is too broad a subject for just one tag.

Comment: I alerted the original moderator that undid the change the first time; Bill has reverted it again just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search isn't broken here. The `android-wear` tag became a synonym of `android` recently, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?search=android-wear

This is directly flying in the face of the tag being un-synonymised recently: [Undo [android-wear] -> [android] tag synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276120/undo-android-wear-android-tag-synonym). Others have noticed, there already is a post on Meta.SO about this, calling for the synonym to be reversed once more:

[Undo the [android-wear] -> [android] tag synonym again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289310/undo-the-android-wear-android-tag-synonym-again)